# PyroCMS: How to fix <Div class>

Tags: php, pyrocms

I can't seem to get  to work within page layouts. Even when I straight up copy and paste the code from the documentation ( http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/concepts/organization ).

```
<h1>{{ page:title }}</h1>
<div class="one_third">{{ page:body }}</div>
<div class="two_thirds">{{ widgets:instance id="1"}}</div>
```

The information shows from both the widget and the page, yet they are stacked rather than in separate columns.

http://tinypic.com/r/2hfq8er/6 <---screenshot

I remember successfully using the  tag in layouts on the last pyrocms site I tested, yet have no idea what I did wrong this time. Thanks for your help.

Note: I have also tried using div class in html on the pages themselves and though the page splits as it should, the content still stacks in one of the columns. Despite being listed between the opening and closing of the later column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was already answered on the PyroCMS forums, but for the record of answering the question here:

Those classes are examples of the sort of thing people do with page layouts.

There is no default "grid system" provided. If you would like to use one you are welcome to go and download Twitter Bootstrap of whatever other grid system you are interested in using.